# Placemarks displayed in order / defining which overlap others

Tags: kml, google-earth

I have created a kml with over 500 placemarks in a country. I divided them in four folders/categories and assigned them separated icons respectively.

I have noticed that when zooming out, the placemark icons overlap each other in a random order. I wanted a certain category of icons to be displayed on top of others in a hierarchy order. I tried setting altitude and also order of placemarks in kml, but it doesn't help. I have yet to come across a solution to this when searching on the web.

Does anybody know if there is a way to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to place a ground overlay image over another you use the [`<drawOrder>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#draworder) element. For lines and polygons you use [`<gx:drawOrder>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#gxdraworder). For points these drawOrder elements are ignored.

If the points are close together then only way to try to make one placemark icon appear over another is if it has a higher altitude. NOTE: You must make sure you have the *altitudeMode* defined otherwise altitude value is ignored.

In the example below, the Placemark icon for P1 is drawn over the Placemark P2.

```
<Document>
    <!-- style definitions here... -->

    <Placemark>
        <name>P1</name>         
        <styleUrl>#s1</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>98.92,43.55,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>

    <Placemark>
        <name>P2</name>
        <styleUrl>#s2</styleUrl>
        <Point>
            <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
            <coordinates>98.92001,43.55001,2</coordinates>
        </Point>
    </Placemark>
</Document>
```

In general, if the altitude different is 1 meter or less the first placemark is drawn first. If the altitude is at least 2 meters then the high placemark is drawn first.

Generally the higher altitude placemark icons are drawn over lower altitude icons **but if you rotate and tilt then sometimes the lower altitude icons are drawn over one with higher altitude** so this technique does not always work. The terrain and tilt angle makes this a non-trivial problem for Google Earth to solve. Without Google Earth adding support for an explicit *drawOrder* element added to the Point geometry (as with lines and polygons) you don't have full absolute control over the icon drawing as you would like.

Likewise, the placemark label names can have a color and scale factor but you don't have fine-grain control of its placement with respect to the icon -- the labels will "float" around the icons as you move around.

Comment: Hi @JasonM1,

Thank you for your reply. I tried before the same thing that you mentioned. Retrying from zero using your way of defining them, I set additional P# placemarks and while P5 is higher in altitude (16m) than P4 (11m), when zooming out P4 displays over P5 icon. They're both set relativeToGround in the altitude mentioned above. What gives?
You could try creating three different placemarks that are close in coordinates, separate them in three folders, make a copy of them within their folders and move the copies close-by. Save as, restart GE. You'll notice the issue.
Let me know...

Comment: Hmmm. If I try P1 at 11 meters and P2 at 16 meters then P2 displays over P1. Likewise if P1 at 0 meters and P2 at 2 meters. What version of Google Earth are you using? Might help if you post KML sample and screenshot.

Comment: I'm currently running GE 7.0.3.8542.
As for the screenshot, you may take a look at the [screenshot](http://www.sidalbania.org/register/captured.jpg) where P4 is higher than P5.
I've uploaded the [test kml](http://www.sidalbania/org/register/test.kml) for you to see.

Comment: see screenshot but URL to test.kml not found

Comment: Mystery solved. Looks in general that in GE 7.1.1.1580 the P5 (alt=16m) is drawn over P4 (alt=11m) but if you rotate and tilt then sometimes the drawing is shows P4 (lower altitude icon) over top of P5. Without Google Earth supporting an explicit drawOrder element in Point you don't full absolute control over the icon drawing as you do for lines/polygons.